# OCR text+markings

Tags: ocr

Is there a free OCR library out there that can extract text as well as detect some markings on the text?  I realize this is an extremely vague proposition and such functionality would be highly dependent on what type of "markings" I want to detect.

But as far as I can tell no such thing even exists, except for a few commercial packages that claim to convert scanned pages into editable files while preserving some semblance of the original page layout.  I'm looking rather for a LIBRARY that I program with.

My specific application of such a library would be this:

1. Print a page.
2. Use a pencil to underline key words.
3. Scan the page.
4. Run a program that converts the scanned page image into some text format that marks each of the underlined words.  For example, an RTF file where each pencil-underlined word has been bolded.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use OCR? if you have the original document available to you, I think that opens much simpler venues...

Comment: You mean by the human hand?  Sure, but I'm asking about AUTOMATIC functionality.

Comment: No I mean, if you have the _original digital document_ available (you are talking about printing it after all), you can do easier things AUTOMATICALLY.

Comment: For instance, you could "print" a second copy to an image and compare that image with your scan. From there, you only have to decide which differences are noise and which are underlining, and you have to find a way to translate a position from the image to a word in the original document. I'd say those tasks are easier to program and your result will be better as well.

Answer (score 0):

Best free OCR tool is probably still Tesseract. You'd have to modify the code yourself to identify your markup's positioning relative to the scanned text.

When I last checked a couple of years ago good, free, OCR libaries were thin on the ground. Even closed source offering are generally not worth the bother, unless you want to spend $$$ on them.